# How to create tab panel dynamically in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a model and store in my code. As per functionality, I want to create tabs dynamically from store. Can you share code snippet? Assuming that there is corresponding model and store.

Comment: Listen for the store load event, build up the array of items you want to add, call `add()` on the tab panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you first need to create Tab panel

```
datatabpanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                layout: 'card',
            }),
```

and then Inside tab panel you to `add` your element. In this case I am giving example of adding grid into tab panel.

we are first taking the response by using Ajax and from that response we are build the grid. Once grid is ready we are add to the tab panel dynamically.

```
load: function() {
    var url = '',
    proxyMethod = 'GET';
    url = SomeURL;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
          url: url,
          headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              'X-HTTP-Method-Override': "PUT"
          },
          success: function(res, args) {
              var data = Ext.decode(res.responseText);
              me.view.mainData = data;
              if (data.ROOT.DATA) {
                  me.buildGrids(data.ROOT.DATA.D, data.ROOT.HEADER);
                }
          }
        })
  }




 buildGrids: function(data, metaData) {
        var p = this,
            me = p.view,
            cnt = me.down("container[name=gridtabs]"), // This is your container where you placing your grid. You named that as gridtabs. 
            datatabpanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                layout: 'card',
            }),
            newdatagrids = [];
        data = Ext.isObject(data) ? [data] : data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var value = data[i].NAME; // You can extract from your attributes.
            var datasetgrids = Ext.create({  
                xtype: 'SomeGrid',
                storeXml:{"ROOT":{ "DATA":data[i],"HEADER":metaData}}, // This is also depended on how to data is coming.
                gridId: data[i]["ID"],
            });
            newdatagrids.push(datasetgrids);
        }
        cnt.removeAll();
        datatabpanel.add(newdatagrids);
        datatabpanel.setActiveTab(0);
        cnt.add(datatabpanel);
    },
```

In code you can see we are creating one array `newdatagrids` and then puting my grid into this array by using `newdatagrids.push(datasetgrids);`

Once my `newdatagrids` is ready i am adding this to my tabpanel by using `datatabpanel.add(newdatagrids);`.

**Note** :  This is just sample code. You have to make/change/modify this kind of code as per your requirment.

There are aslo lots of good example are given in docs. Please have a look. [Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html)

Comment: There's no "scroll" config. Also, a tab panel defaults to a card layout, specifying fit is, at best, redundant. Also, it would be better to maintain the configuration objects and defer all of that til add time.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Noted. Thank you for pointed this out. . Didn't checked the doc while writing this code. I just assumed pre definition. yes.. that would be better I just given a idea and focused on how things work. These points i will keep in mind in future.